# Facebook Application Invite using Graph API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a website in which i have a feature of inviting facebook friends, when i invite a friend, he will get a notification on his facebook account,I want the functionality that when he clicks on notification he'll redirected to my website(for eg www.abc.com/signup)
How can i achieve this i am using Graph API, also after clicking on notification he will able to know from whom the invitation has arrived.
How can i redirect  user to my website  after clicking on notification(with any query string parameters)